# Onsen Sliding Menu: linking to local files without doing away with slider

Tags: onsen-ui

I am tryin to use Onsen Slidingmenu.
Il is slick and works just fine but...
I would like to use it to call diiferent mini-sites located within the app.
Sounds easy but... those mini-sites have to have their own "index.html" pages and sub-directories.
So when I have one of the links of the Onsen slidingmenu call the fist mini-site I write:

```
<ons-list-item class="bottom-menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('dir01/index.html', {closeMenu: true})">
          To Mini-site-One
 </ons-list-item>
```

And it works (unbelievable!) :p

BUT, the sliding menu disappears.
you probably guessed my question: How can I make it persistent throughout all mini-sites, whatever the page loaded?

Many thanks!

Comment: ...maybe it's just not doable with Onsen's slider?

Comment: The sliding menu should still be there when you switch the main page. It looks like there's something else going on.

Do you get any JavaScript errors?

Comment: Thank you Andreas for chiming in :-)
Here is the complet page of my code:

Comment: Thank you Andreas for chiming in :-)

er.. you're  right the menu IS stll there. I was testing on my browser and it seemed vanished (but is was just clumsy mouse-playing on my part).Thanks for your help it encouraged me to "dig" deeper, (no coding this time though ;-)
Great app!! Thanks again Andreas. Consider this is an answer ' I'll mark it as such :-)

Comment: Glad you solved it :)

Comment: Thanks! Hope to read you soon :-)